# Can bounded random variable have infinite expectation?

Tags: probability, expectation

Can bounded (possibly continuous) random variable have infinite expectation? If no, how can we show it?

Comment: Sorry my brain thought something and I wroute something differend. The moment in question is the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If a random variable $X$ is bounded, then $E[|X|] \le E[M] = M$ for some constant $M>0$ due to the monotonicity of the expectation.  Write the second moment $E[X^2]$ and establish an upper bound in a similar way.

Comment: Thank you. To asses that the mean is also bounded, we use the fact, that absolute convergence implies convergence? And does it actually impy convergence?

Comment: @JanVainer Only montonicity of the expectation is used.  You mean $E[|X|] < \infty \implies E[X] < \infty$?  That's true in Lebesgue's sense.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i meant. Thank you.